# ORA-01031: insufficient privileges while refreshing materialized view | Oracle

Tags: database, oracle

> My question may be a duplicate or too easy. But I tried all the solutions I googled. Didn't help.

I have two databases. Data entry and editing are performed in the first database.
The second database only prints data. All the tables in the second database are created by materialized view. I need to refresh the **materialized views** to ensure that the changes in the primary database are reflected in the secondary database. Now I have a user with grant access (username sys, type SYSDBA). When I log in with the main sys user and enter refresh, the following error appears:

```
Error starting at line : 78 in command -
BEGIN dbms_mview.refresh ('VIEW_NAME'); END;
Error report -
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges 
ORA-06512: on  "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 2957
ORA-06512: on  "SYS.DBMS_ISNAPSHOT", line 213
ORA-01403: data not found
ORA-06512: on  "SYS.DBMS_ISNAPSHOT", line 193
ORA-06512: on  "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 2791
ORA-06512: on  "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 3197
ORA-06512: on  "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 3228
ORA-06512: on  "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 15
ORA-06512: on  line 1
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
```

I have also created several other grant access users. But all users are getting this error.
My script as follow:

```
set timing on;


spool d:\irs_mv.log;
set timing on;

exec dbms_mview.refresh ('VIEW_1');
exec dbms_mview.refresh ('VIEW_2');
exec dbms_mview.refresh ('VIEW_...');
spool off;
```

Also i tried as follow:

```
BEGIN
exec dbms_mview.refresh ('VIEW_1');
END;
```

But all the solutions I googled are returning one error.
How can I solve this error?
Now my server:

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- Oracle 18c, OAS
  Thanks!

Comment: First off, never, never, NEVER, use any user with the SYSDBA role, and especially not SYS itself, for ANY application-related operations, or to own application data or objects. I cannot stress enough how huge of a security risk that is. What happens when you refresh the MV as the user that actually owns the MV? Is the a `FAST REFRESH` type of MV? Are there any MV Logs on the tables in the source database?

Comment: Thanks @pmdba, I tried with another user for refresh but didn't help. What could this be? It was a refresh before. It's not working now. Tried with any other user. All logs included inside source database.

Comment: Was the "other user" the owner of the materialized views? Have any of the source tables been dropped and recreated?

Comment: @pmdba,  there is no any dropped tables or recreated tables.  But we cloned full server for testing development.

Answer (score 1):

There is a variety of potential reasons for this error, depending on how the mview is setup (fast/complete, local/remote etc etc).

MOS note 1231613.1 covers each of these scenarios with workarounds/solutions for each.